# Как использовать результат подзапроса в другом подзапросе

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос, oracle11g

Вот пример запроса:

```
select (select 10-2 from dual) hh, (select hh-5 from dual) zz from dual
```

При попытке выполнения, получаю ошибку:

> ORA-00904: "HH": недопустимый идентификатор
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 1 Column: 44

Понимаю, что судя по всему допускаю синтаксическую ошибку.

Как сделать правильно?

Comment: сослаться на алиас столбца на том же уровне запроса никак не выйдет. А подзапросы select в списке выборки - это последнее средство, если больше ничего не помогает. Надо стараться минимизировать количество таких подзапросов. Практически всегда та же задача решается join или иными средствами и тогда и необходимости обращаться к алиасам не возникает

Answer (score 4):

Ссылаться на алиас столбца в том же уровне запроса нельзя.

Попробуйте так:

```
with s1 as (select 10-2 hh from dual), s2 as (select hh, hh-5 from s1) select * from s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Так сделать у вас не получится. В зависимости от поставленной задачи можно переписать запрос так:

```
select hh, hh-5 as zz from (select (select 10-2 from dual) as hh  from dual)
```

или так:

```
select (select 10-2 from dual) as hh, (select 10-2 from dual) - 5 as zz  from dual
```

Comment: Задача чисто для себя понять возможно ли использовать результат выполнения соседнего подзапроса)

Comment: Я не понимаю Ваш вопрос. Что значит "соседний подзапрос" ? Как уже написал Mike ссылаться на алиас столбца на одном и том же уровне запроса не выйдет. Пока не понятно, чем вам не подходит первый из предложенных мной вариантов. Или почему нельзя переписать запрос через `join`. Дайте больше информации о вашей задаче

Comment: @Alexey, Ответ чисто для вас - прочитайте про порядок выполнения условий в запросе. Вот тут, например: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_having_clause.html
Если вкратце - подзапросы выполняются одновременно, поэтому результат одного не может быть указан в другом. И еще вам долнжо стать понятно почему, например, результат подзапроса нельзя использовать в WHERE. а вот в ORDER BY можно.

Answer (score 0):

```
select hh.xx-5 zz,hh.xx hh from(select 10-2 xx from dual) hh
```